# Why is my image path not render my image in vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am attempting to access an image in vue.js and render to the DOM, but it is not working.

This is the code :

```
<template lang="html">

  <div>
    <h1 class=""> {{ Tex }}</h1>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3><b>Connect Soft documents</b></h3>
          <p class="lead">Allow documents that feed into each other to provide a consistent, untainted view of the financial, operational and social behaviour of the institution.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img src="ConnectDocuments.png" alt="Documents" class="pull-right img-responsive imG" width="250" height="250">
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="row">
        <!-- position image to the right when on desktop,, but allow image to occupy the whole  webpage  when the device is less the 768px-->
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <h3><b>Improve decision models</b></h3>
          <p class="lead">Use statistical modelling to identify patterns and anomalies in the data that can help in
        making better decisions.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./assets/Statistics.png" alt="Statistics" width="350px" height="270px" class="pull-right img-responsive imG">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</template>
```

This is an image of the project folder to see how I am referencing the image path.

[image: vue project setup]

Comment: try `src = "../assets/Statistics.png"`

Comment: Which component is in your code?

Comment: @YannBertrand What do you mean?
 The image Statistics.png is in the assets folder. The product component is in the pages folder and it contains the <img src = "./assets/Statistics.png"> element.

Comment: I didn't know you were talking about the Product component ;)

Comment: @YannBertrand Oh my bad. I just want to images to show on the product page and it's not. lol

Comment: @cktang I added the extra dot but it did not work.

Comment: Try with `../../assets/Statistics.png`

Comment: @YannBertrand It worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled ../../assets/Statistics.png